# What is the difference between screen-256 color and xterm-256color

Tags: linux, tmux, xterm

I've just started using [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) and I'm having trouble with my colorscheme in `vim`.  I've using the [zenburn](http://slinky.imukuppi.org/zenburnpage/) color scheme and it works fine with the default terminal settings in Ubuntu 10.04.

However, when I run `vim` in a tmux session the colors don't look good at all.  I've done some searches to try to figure out what the problem is and one thing I found is [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/399296/256-color-support-for-vim-background-in-tmux) where the solution involved allowing tmux to using `screen-256color` and removing the setting in `.bashrc` which was setting it to `xterm-256color`.

So I am curious what the difference is between `xterm-256color` and `screen-256color` but I haven't found a good explanation yet.

Comment: Don't set `$TERM` in `.bashrc`; it's just asking for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 23):

`tmux` is a terminal emulator, since each pane must behave as a separate terminal; its emulation is not exactly the same as that of `xterm` or `gnome-terminal`, for historical reasons (it instead matches `screen`, which predates most of the GUI terminal emulators).  It therefore requires a different terminal description to behave properly.

Setting `$TERM` manually is usually a bad idea specifically for this reason; it will usually be set correctly by itself, with some exceptions usually related to compatibility (older Solaris doesn't understand `xterm-256color`, for example).

Comment: Okay I had exactly this problem: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167843/tmux-vim-colorscheme-background-is-not-showing?noredirect=1#comment276298_167843. So where should I put the $TERM then to screen-256color?

Comment: in your .tmux.conf:

set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"