# vim backgroundcolor in tmux - how to force zsh to use screen instead of xterm in tmux

Tags: vim, zsh, tmux

I am having the same problem like the questioner in [256 color support for vim background in tmux](https://superuser.com/questions/399296/256-color-support-for-vim-background-in-tmux/399326#399326).

In my normal terminal with `zsh`, I have no background color issues in `vim`, but when I run it inside `tmux`, I get issues with the background colors.

Apparently, there is a problem with using `screen` instead of `xterm`:

Outside Tmux: `echo $TERM` results in `screen` 
Inside Tmux: `echo $TERM` results in `xterm`

In my .zshrc and .tmux.conf I have set

```
TERM=screen-256color
```

but it doesn't effect anything. (I also tried `TERM=screen`)

How can I force `tmux` to use `screen`?

EDIT: 
thanks to htor, I added `set -g default-terminal "screen"` (also tried `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"`) in .tmux.conf and in .zshrc `export TERM=screen-256color`.

Now I get:

Outside Tmux: `echo $TERM` results in `screen-256color` 
Inside Tmux: `echo $TERM` results in `echoscreen-256color` (<- looks a little bit weird with, is the output correct?)

What else can I do to solve the background color issue in vim inside tmux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As explained here](http://snk.tuxfamily.org/log/vim-256color-bce.html), disable **Background Color Erase** (BCE) by clearing the `t_ut` terminal option (run `:set t_ut=` in Vim and then press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to refresh the terminal's display) so that color schemes work properly when Vim is used inside tmux and GNU screen.

Answer (score 1):

To set the default terminal variable for `tmux` change your `.tmux.conf` to:

```
set -g default-terminal "screen"
```

The shell syntax for setting variables will not work in `.tmux.conf`. In your `.zshrc` you should export the value of `TERM` to make sure all shells inherits this value in your environment:

```
export TERM=screen-256color
```

Comment: Thanks htor, with your advice i get now 
with echo $TERM in- and outside tmux "screen-256color". But the vim background-color issue inside tmux still remains.

What else can i do to get rid of this annoying issue (i use tmux and vim a lot)?

Comment: @Lennier Have you tried using `xterm` as `TERM` value and `screen` in `tmux`? Can you post a pastie of your `.vimrc` in your question?