# Vim Colorscheme Weirdness for Background (Not Non-Text Area)

Tags: vim, colors

I've been messing around with vim color schemes, and some of them (this is Molokai) have a weird effect where the background is different than the text background. I thought this:

```
hi NonText      guifg=darkgray      guibg=white         gui=none
hi NonText      ctermfg=darkgray    ctermbg=white       cterm=none
```

Would be the right settings, but those only affect the space at bottom of the page. What are the settings for to adjust the background in the text area that does not contain text/spaces?

[image: Two Color Background]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer here appears to be an issue with TMUX:

[256 color support for vim background in tmux](https://superuser.com/questions/399296/256-color-support-for-vim-background-in-tmux)

TMUX really wants the term to be "screen-256color" or "screen".

You can test it by doing background erase, according to this.

https://serverfault.com/questions/268555/how-to-tell-vim-to-extend-the-background-color-to-the-whole-screen

Answer (score 1):

Unless I misunderstand the question, I think you want to set the `Normal` highlight group to your desired colors. `NonText` is not what you seem to think it is. From the help:

```
                                                        *hl-NonText*
NonText     '~' and '@' at the end of the window, characters from
            'showbreak' and other characters that do not really exist in
            the text (e.g., ">" displayed when a double-wide character
            doesn't fit at the end of the line).
```