# Solarized in Konsole + tmux + vim

Tags: vim, tmux, konsole, solarized

Solarized color scheme works fine when using [Konsole + vim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPVqd.png), but I can't figure out how to properly configure my computer for a [Konsole + tmux +vim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWPiV.png) usage (please see screenshots on the links).

Below, the configuration I am using.

At Konsole:

```
user:~$ echo $TERM
xterm-256color
user:~$ cat .tmux.conf | grep terminal
set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color" #"screen-256color" gives the same result
user:~$ cat .vimrc
:filetype plugin on    
syntax enable
set term=xterm-256color
let g:solarized_termcolors=256
set t_Co=256
set background=dark
colorscheme solarized
```

At tmux:

```
user:~$ echo $TERM
xterm-256color
```

Would you have any suggestion, please?

Comment: Maybe you should set `term` to `screen-256color` instead of `xterm-256color`. [http://superuser.com/a/399326/431697]
Also, try invoking tmux with the `-2` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/term-strings/:

"
A certain piece of very misleading advice is often given online to users having problems with the way certain command-line applications are displaying in their terminals. [...] This misinformation sometimes extends to suggesting that users put the forced TERM change into their shell startup scripts. The reason this is such a bad idea is that it forces your shell to assume what your terminal is, and thereby disregards the initial terminal identity string sent by the emulator."

Following their suggestion, I have erased from ~/.bashrc, ~/.vimrc and ~/.tmux.conf every mention to the terminal.

Now I have at Konsole:

```
user:~$ echo $TERM
xterm
```

at tmux:

```
user:~$ echo $TERM
xterm-256color
```

and everything works well.

Answer (score -1):

I was looking for many solutions and found Flattened color scheme which is basically Solarized but tweaked so good that it worked out of the box in tmux on my machine. Link:
https://github.com/romainl/flattened